# Semicolon is not working in "begin...end block" in mysql in Procedure

Tags: mysql

I have seen some answer about this. But those cant solve my problem

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_while_loop; 

Delimeter // 

CREATE PROCEDURE test_while_loop()
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count_ FROM job_applicant;

  END 
// 


Delimeter;
```

But shows unexpected near ';'

Answer (score 0):

in your procedure you forget to `DECLARE count_ variable`. add blow line in the procedure your problem will solve

```
DECLARE count_ INT DEFAULT 0;
```

Try this.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_while_loop; 

DELIMITER // 

CREATE PROCEDURE test_while_loop()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE count_ INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count_ FROM job_applicant;    
  END //     
DELIMITER ;
```

Right keyword is `DELIMITER`, not Delimeter

Comment: in which line ? which tool you are using Its workbench ?

Comment: after "Delimiter //" , in every line  where ";"(Semicolon)
stands.... exepts "Delimeter;"

Comment: i have updated my answer. problem is you are write delimeter but it is `DELIMITER`. hope this will work

Comment: after "Delimiter //" , in every line where ";"(Semicolon) stands.... exepts "Delimiter;"

Comment: plz let me know which tool you are using to run this procedure?

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in your last line.

```
Delimiter;
```

should be

```
Delimiter ;
```

(Note the space. Also note the spelling: it's `DELIMITER`, not `DELIMETER`.)

Once that's fixed, you also need to declare the variable `count_`, as Vipin Jain points out. The complete code should be

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_while_loop; 

DELIMITER // 

CREATE PROCEDURE test_while_loop()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE count_ INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO count_
      FROM job_applicant;    
  END //     
DELIMITER ;
```

(Breaking up the **`SELECT`** as I did is strictly a matter of personal preference.)

Comment: I edit the code as you suggest. But the problem shows on the 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count_ FROM job_applicant ;..... where a semicolon exists

Comment: Can you post the complete text of the error message?

Comment: I just typed the above code (that is, mine) into my own system and it compiled with no problem. Your original code gives me `Undeclared variable: count_`. Can you update your post to show us the most recent thing you tried?

Answer (score -1):

You need to make up your mind. You've specified `DELIMITER //` yet you're still using `;`. Of course it gives a syntax error. It's wrong. Use `//` (or don't change the delimiter at all). If the delimiter has been changed to `//` you can't use `;` in the body of the procedure.

NB the final line `Delimeter;`

- is misspelt
- is missing an internal space.

Comment: I have corrected the errors ... I am using mysql attached to xaamp v3.2.2

Comment: It isn't clear whether by correcting the errors you've solved your problem, or, if you haven't solved your problem, which errors you've corrected, and how.

Comment: The point of `delimiter //` is to allow you to use `;` without it being interpreted as the end of the `CREATE` statement.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Curious that I have a number of stored procedures whose body contains `;` and no `DELIMITER` statement anywhere in the system.

Comment: It's a client-specific extension that's required when *entering* the procedure, but isn't stored as part of the procedure. `mysql` and Workbench require it; I seem to recall that phpMyAdmin doesn't, and other tools may do something else entirely.